# SQL Server OLAP CUBES (Tutorials)

Tags: .net, sql-server, olap, cubes

Hope this isnt a repost, at least I didnt find any results that I was happy with on google.

The thing is I don't know much about OLAP connections but I'm decent when it comes to SQL requests but I would like to further my skills

What site, book - would you recommend

Comment: Define OLAP cube. Cube is a constrcut - star schema etc. YYou know that, or you want help with SQL Server Analytical Services (a technology) or the OLAP support commands in TSQL?

Comment: hmm, i would say just a start up guide (noobguide,beginnerstutorial)
i dont know much about start schema or the OLAP support commands :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN has a set of basic tutorials that will help you install/browse a sample OLAP environment.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170208.aspx

These highlight the different areas in an SSAS project.

In terms of querying (MDX) you can look at the **SQL Server Central - Stairway to MDX** series of articles:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72404/